# Как отправить список файлов из базы данных через телеграм бот в проекте django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Пишу небольшой учебный сайт, используя `Django`. Прям в проекте реализован телеграм-бот. Использую библиотеку `Python-telegram-bot`. Мне нужно реализовать возможность отправки ботом пользователю по его поисковому запросу список подходящих текстовых файлов, из тех, что залиты на сайт и хранятся в базе. Никак не могу разобраться как это сделать. Вот фрагмент кода, его нужно переделать с отправки текстового сообщения на отправку списка файлов. Помогите, кто может.

```
def do_search(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
    chat_id=update.message.chat_id
    text=update.message.text

    #Выбираем список всех файлов 
    object_list = Reflist.objects.filter(title__icontains=text)

    reply_text='Ваш ID = {}\n\n{}'.format(chat_id,text)
    update.message.reply_text(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text=reply_text,

    )
```

Comment: возможно документация поможет https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inputfile.html#telegram-inputfile

Comment: Если б помогла, я б тут не пиисал

Comment: А можете добавить код модели `Reflist`? И я правильно понимаю что в этой модели есть вся необходимая информация для того что бы сделать сообщение которое вы хотите отправить в телегу?

Comment: Спасибо, я смог отпраить файл, теперь загвоздка в том, как отправить спиисок файлов одниим сообщением с бота. Так как файлов может быть больше одного

Comment: Как вариант запакуйте их в архив, и получится один файл.

Comment: @AlexSn2020 если нашли решение сами то оформите его как ответ. А то вопрос будет висеть без ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ, но пока не совсем то, что подходит, но уже что-то

```
def do_search(update:Update,context:CallbackContext):
chat_id=update.message.chat_id
text=update.message.text
#Выбираем все данныепоиска в quaryset
object_list = Reflist.objects.filter(title__icontains=text)

update.message.reply_document(
    filename= object_list[0].title,
    document=object_list[0].file,

)
```

Только в этом случае передаётся только первый файл из списка поиска.